# What is the difference between cross validation and calculating R2/ Adjusted R2/ MSE, etc?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

For checking regression model accuracy - R2, Adjusted R2, etc methods are used
Cross Validation is used for checking the same, is it true ? Correct me if I am wrong.

I know there is difference between the two but can't differentiate, getting confused.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to stats.stackechange.  And as such you may find what you are looking for here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339736/perform-cross-validation-on-train-set-or-entire-data-set/339842#339842